# How do i install pycairo Im on windows and this is the error i get when trying to install through pip

Tags: python, windows

so like what  do i do ? and if the answer to download it manually what do i need to do next ? i am using pycharm . i dont really know what a wheel is or what is GTK /..... but i wanted to install cairo so that i could use manim . Thanks for any and all help.

````
Collecting pycairo
  Using cached https://files.pythonhosted.org/packages/3c/1a/c0478ecab31baae50fda9956547788afbd0ca5
63adc52c9b03cab30f17eb/pycairo-1.18.2.tar.gz
Installing collected packages: pycairo
  Running setup.py install for pycairo ... error
    Complete output from command C:\Users\User\PycharmProjects\hello\venv\Scripts\python.exe -u -c
"import setuptools, tokenize;__file__='C:\\Users\\User\\AppData\\Local\\Temp\\pip-install-4lgps5e9\
\pycairo\\setup.py';f=getattr(tokenize, 'open', open)(__file__);code=f.read().replace('\r\n', '\n')
;f.close();exec(compile(code, __file__, 'exec'))" install --record C:\Users\User\AppData\Local\Temp
\pip-record-p805hmez\install-record.txt --single-version-externally-managed --compile --install-hea
ders C:\Users\User\PycharmProjects\hello\venv\include\site\python3.7\pycairo:
    running install
    running build
    running build_py
    creating build
    creating build\lib.win32-3.7
    creating build\lib.win32-3.7\cairo
    copying cairo\__init__.py -> build\lib.win32-3.7\cairo
    copying cairo\__init__.pyi -> build\lib.win32-3.7\cairo
    copying cairo\py.typed -> build\lib.win32-3.7\cairo
    running build_ext
    building 'cairo._cairo' extension
    creating build\temp.win32-3.7
    creating build\temp.win32-3.7\Release
    creating build\temp.win32-3.7\Release\cairo
    C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio\2019\Community\VC\Tools\MSVC\14.22.27905\bin\Hos
tX86\x86\cl.exe /c /nologo /Ox /W3 /GL /DNDEBUG /MT -DPYCAIRO_VERSION_MAJOR=1 -DPYCAIRO_VERSION_MIN
OR=18 -DPYCAIRO_VERSION_MICRO=2 -IC:\Users\User\PycharmProjects\hello\venv\include -IC:\Users\User\
AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37-32\include -IC:\Users\User\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Pyt
hon37-32\include "-IC:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio\2019\Community\VC\Tools\MSVC\14.
22.27905\include" "-IC:\Program Files (x86)\Windows Kits\10\include\10.0.18362.0\ucrt" "-IC:\Progra
m Files (x86)\Windows Kits\10\include\10.0.18362.0\shared" "-IC:\Program Files (x86)\Windows Kits\1
0\include\10.0.18362.0\um" "-IC:\Program Files (x86)\Windows Kits\10\include\10.0.18362.0\winrt" "-
IC:\Program Files (x86)\Windows Kits\10\include\10.0.18362.0\cppwinrt" /Tccairo/device.c /Fobuild\t
emp.win32-3.7\Release\cairo/device.obj
    device.c
    C:\Users\User\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-install-4lgps5e9\pycairo\cairo\pycairo.h(37): fatal error
C1083: Cannot open include file: 'cairo.h': No s
uch file or directory
    error: command 'C:\\Program Files (x86)\\Mic
rosoft Visual Studio\\2019\\Community\\VC\\Tools
\\MSVC\\14.22.27905\\bin\\HostX86\\x86\\cl.exe'
failed with exit status 2 ]```
````